# Inheriting Locale does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, mootools, locale, mootools-more

I am using MooTools 1.4.1 (full More) and experience a problem with inheriting

```
Locale.define('de-CH').inherit('de-DE', 'Date');
```

When I use this Locale (de-CH), and access it as follows

```
var myLocale = Locale.getCurrent()
```

myLocale.sets.Date is NOT defined, the only thing that is defined is myLocale.sets.FormValidator, but that is only because this is explicitly set and not inherited.

When validating Dates, for example, this results in an error, obviously.

So, in my eyes, I am doing something wrong or the inheriting-Mechanism of Locale has a bug.

Anyone has experience? Thanks.

Comment: `Locale.inherit('de-CH', 'de-DE', 'Date');` and `Locale.use('de-CH')` should then have that

Comment: Where do I have to put that? Inside the MooTools file or inside my own code? Currently, the MooTools code has this line `Locale.define('de-CH').inherit('de-DE', 'Date');`

Comment: Well, anyway, it does not solve the problem. There must be some kind of bug anyway, when in the MooTools More sources, there is an explicit statement to inherit 'Date' from 'de-DE', but it doesn't show up at all in the Locale object? Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to directly use the `sets` property of a locale. The `sets` property will only contain the sets defined on that locale. Inherited sets are only defined on the inherited locale (which you can actually see by looking at `myLocale.inherits.sets`, but that's not supposed to be used directly either).

Instead, using `myLocale.get('Date')` will return the set you need.

Using `Locale.get('Date')` will work as well and will always return the set of the currently active locale (set through `Locale.use('de-CH')`).

You can also use calls like `.get('Date.months')` to get a specific property.

More information can be found in [MooTools' Locale documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Locale/Locale).

Comment: Sounds good and makes sense, but then there is a bug in Form.Validator.addAllThese, where it adds the "validate-date" Object, namely in the test-Function: `var dateLocale = Locale.getCurrent().sets.Date` , which, if Locale is an inherited one, undefined! So my problems are not related to Locale but rather to a bug in Form.Validator. Or am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: That, indeed, is a bug in `Form.Validator`. Fixed in `master`:
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/issues/1168